# Where does the bcp format file go when created using the BCP utility?

Tags: sql-server-2005, cmd, bcp

I am trying to create a bcp format file for a table in my database using the bcp utility. Based on what I found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), I came up with the following cmd command:

`bcp dbName..tableName format nul -c -f tableName.fmt -T`

It works with no output. First of all, is that what's supposed to happen? Does that mean that it ran successfully?

Second, what happened to my format file? I can't find it anywhere. I searched my hard drive, as well as the drive that the server's on, and it's not there. I would think that it would be on the drive that I ran the command from, but I actually ran it from a query window. Can that be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For me, it is created in "C:\Windows\System32"

But you can just specify your own location using a root file path, and then create the file anywhere you want:

```
bcp dbName..tableName format nul -c -f "c:\logs\tableName.fmt" -T
```

Answer (score 1):

The format file should have been created in the directory where the bcp command was run:

[image]